# How to paint terrain details (e.g. grass billboards) programmatically?

Tags: unity, c#, textures, procedural-generation, terrain

In Unity, is it possible to paint terrain details such as billboarded grass textures programmatically? (The kind that appear vertical and wave according to wind settings.)

### What I know so far (or think I do):

- **Terrain.TerrainData.terrainLayers** holds the textures (dirt/rock/grass/etc.) that can be painted “flat” onto the terrain
- **Terrain.TerrainData.detailPrototypes** holds the billboard-able grass/vegetation textures that can be painted to appear vertical / waving in the wind
- **Terrain.TerrainData.treePrototypes** holds the 3D tree models imported for placement
- **Terrain.TerrainData.treeInstances** (I would guess) holds actual placements of trees on the terrain

### What I don’t know:

- **MY MAIN GOAL:** “Paint” billboarded grass details at specific positions on the terrain programmatically
- Alphamaps (and splatmaps??) seem to figure into this somehow, but I don’t know how
- Unity's example found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetAlphamaps.html) “blend[s] the two terrain textures according to the steepness of the slope at each point”, but that’s not exactly what I’m trying to do.

- I also found [this fairly ancient (2013) blog post](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/procedural-terrain-splatmapping/), but I don't see any reference to adding billboarded grass details in it either.

Hopefully this makes sense to someone willing to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Not able to answer all your questions, but I've previously generated both the terrain and splat maps externally, then imported them. The splat map is just a texture where each channel is used to represent "intensity of surface type x" in the final texture (if you have more than 4 types of surface, Unity uses multiple textures and renders in multiple passes, at least un URP). So it should be a case of finding the splat texture(s) backing the terrain and adding to one channel (whilst removing from others if you don't want blending)

Comment: With "Programmatically", do you mean in form of an editor script or while the game is running? (Full disclosure: I couldn't answer either question without doing some research. But I find it very likely that the approach would differ in these two cases)

Comment: @Basic and Philipp -- Thank you both for your rapid responses.

Philipp -- By "programmatically," I mean generating terrain data at runtime.

Basic -- Regarding alpha/splatmaps, I've read more about these based on your very clear explanation. I'll need to examine an alphamap for an existing terrain ... mainly I want to see if I can distinguish the textures painted "flat" to the surface and those that are detail textures, billboarded like grass and vegetation. I'll examine when I get back to my Unity computer and then follow up here.